# Angular 13 http 405 error when deep linking IIS

Tags: angular

I have an app that works perfectly when I browse to it using the root folder but I need to specify a root depending on where I am linking from.
I've added hashing to get over 404 errors but now have these 405 errors

If I link to ../my-app/   my route will redirect to ../my-app/#/myDefaultPage
If I then refresh the page it is fine

If I link directly to ../my-app/#/myDefaultPage it is fine under development port 4200 but when running on IIS I get a white screen with 405 error.

If I link directy to ../my-app/#/myAlternatePage  I get the same error and yet if i navigate to ../my-app/ first then change the url manually it works.

These pages call an $http service.

I can see some error info coming back which links to :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-error-405-website

but I cant understand what is trying to tell me.

Help would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE] I found that I had put :

```
   { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
```

in my app.module

> ```
> @NgModule({
> imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
> exports: [RouterModule], })
> ```

Where I was calling the local HTTP requests I needed to get the current location to work out a relative path to the folder but the location HREF on a refreshed page included the #/route so I had to split that out by using window.location.href.split('#')[0]  I guess I could have used the location.origin plus the location.pathname instead but it works for me as is.